# Save the output in temporary memory under QGIS Plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, for-loop

I am trying to make a simple plugin, from the input as a vector layer then processed with a Field Calculator function (But I want the ouput from this process to be saved in temporary memory or in other words the output to enter the next step function as an input) after that I want to do a Rasterized function.

I have tried to create the code :

```
def setVariables(self):

    self.rooftop = self.getRooftopLayer()
    self.rain = self.getRainfallLayer()
    self.potvol = self.dlg.le_potvol.text()


def Rasterize (self):


    alg_params = {
        'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'area',
        'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
        'FIELD_TYPE': 1,
        'FORMULA': ' $area ',
        'INPUT': self.rooftop,
        'NEW_FIELD': True,
        'OUTPUT': QStringLiteral( "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT" )
    }

    outputs ['FieldCalculator'] = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', alg_params, feedback=feedback)

    feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    alg_params = {
        'BURN': 0,
        'DATA_TYPE': 5,
        'EXTENT': outputs['FieldCalculator']['OUTPUT'],
        'FIELD': 'area',
        'HEIGHT': 30,
        'INIT': None,
        'INPUT': outputs['FieldCalculator']['OUTPUT'],
        'INVERT': False,
        'NODATA': 0,
        'OPTIONS': '',
        'UNITS': 0,
        'WIDTH': 30,
        'OUTPUT': self.potvol
    }

    outputs['RasterizeVectorToRaster'] = processing.run('gdal:rasterize', alg_params, feedback=feedback)


def addLayers(self):

    self.iface.addRasterLayer(self.potvol, str.split(os.path.basename(self.potvol), ".")[0])
```

What statement I should add?

Answer (score 1):

Add next lines. In your case you may want to add to `def Rasterize(self):`

```
def Rasterize(self):

    outputs = {} # ADD THIS LINE

    ### Your processing lines
    outputs['process1_name'] = processing.run(...)
    #...
    outputs['process2_name'] = processing.run(...)
    ###

    # Add next lines to the same scope/block with 'outputs[".."] =' and customize
    folder = "c:/ADD_A_FOLDER_PATH/" # remember last slash
    for k, v in outputs.items():
        mem_layer = v['OUTPUT']
        path = folder + k + ".shp" # k: process name
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(mem_layer,
                                                path,
                                                None,
                                                mem_layer.crs(),
                                                "ESRI Shapefile")
    ####
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried but still shows an error

#FieldCalculator Process     
 
processing.run ('qgis:fieldcalculator',...'OUTPUT': "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT" })
        
folder = "C:\Iqbal\Thesis Plugin\rwh_yield/"
for k, v in outputs.items():
            mem_layer = v['OUTPUT']
            path = folder + k ['FieldCalculator']+ ".shp"
             QgsVectorFileWriter..

 #Rasterized process using input from Field Calculator
        
processing.run('gdal:rasterize',...'EXTENT': mem_layer,..'INPUT': mem_layer,...'OUTPUT': self.potvol })

It showed "NameError: name 'outputs' is not defined"

Comment: Use / (forward slash)  (or \\ two back slahes) in path or add `r` before path. Please review this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953843/5569709

Comment: The error refered to the "outputs is not defined in 

for k, v in outputs.items():

Comment: Did you add `outputs = {}` line before using it?

Comment: ah yes! but now is coming another error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mem_layer' referenced before assignment

Comment: Did you add `mem_layer = v['OUTPUT']`?

Comment: Yes I did Mr. Kadir, I placed the folder = ... in between of the two process